# Слово "издал" - ударение

Tags: орфоэпия

Почему *пр**о**дал, п**о**дал, **о**тдал, в**ы**дал, пр**и**дал, з**а**дал, р**о**здал, пр**е**дал, преп**о**дал*, ***но*** *изд**а**л*?

Кстати, я никогда не слышал, чтобы говорили "преп**о**дал" (как предлагают словари, не разговорный вариант, а основной) — только "препод**а**л". Какие будут мнения по этому поводу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Хотел комментарий написать, но там тесно оказалось.*

В чем вопрос? Приставка "**ИЗ**/**ИС**" никогда не оттягивает на себя ударения с корня глагола. Именно глагола, *издавна, исстари, изморозь* - это другое. А так: *избить, испить, изжить, извести*.

Что касается преп**о**дал - да, этот вариант как нормативный стремительно устаревает.

Под влиянием, видимо, форм от *под**а**ть, передать* и т.п., да и самого инфинитива *преподать*. Современные словари уже дают *преп**о**дал* и *препод**а**л* как равноправные, можно ожидать, что второе скоро вытеснит первое окончательно. Мне ухо не режет совершенно, это не тот случай, что со "вкл**ю**чит" и подобными.

Comment: Спасибо, behemothus!